# VIM macro editing

Tags: vim, macros

Suppose that I have recorded a long macro with many commands and special characters. Odds are I have made an error somewhere :) How can I edit a macro, correct errors and save it again?

For example:

I wish to copy a line and then increase the digit in it by one.

Macro for this is

```
yyp/\d<C-A>
```

but it is saved as

```
yyp/\d^M^A
```

and I can't see this special characters when I paste the register. I also have to play with 'let' when I wish to copy a register, because standard paste to screen and copy to another register doesn't work. How can I efficiently edit register with special characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean when you say you "can't see the special characters"?  What special characters?  You should be able to see the `^A` and `^M` fine, which represent `<C-A>` and the `<carriage return>` respectively.  That's all you need.

So do just paste the register into a buffer.  Then edit and yank back into a register and execute as a normal macro.  If you want to edit the `<C-A>` to be something else, say, `<C-E>`, then just delete the `^A` that shows up on paste and put a `<C-E>` in by pressing `<C-V><C-E>` (or `<C-Q><C-E>` if you're on Windows with windows compatibility on).  It will show up as `^E`, but that's how it's supposed to be.

Comment: Oh my, thanks for this. The problem was my pasting of register when I was in insert mode, so I couldn't see this ^M and ^A.

Answer (score 0):

Press `<C-r><C-r>q` (here q is the register name) in insert mode. Execute `:h ctrl-r_ctrl-r` to see the details.